# Flask - Logging after response flushed

Tags: python, flask

I know about `app.after_request` and `app.teardown_request`, but is there any way I can run a logging command *after* the response has been flushed to the client.. ie. in a way that doesn't impact the client's performance?

Comment: I doubt this is easily possible. Flask runs on top of [WSGI](http://wsgi.readthedocs.org/en/latest/), which defines how Python code (like Flask or Django) receieve information about the request, and return results. The function itself is pretty simple, but what is import is that Flask will need to return the body of information (and, thus, end its ability to run code, since the thread returns to the code that called flask, such as mod_wsgi). There might be ways around this limitation, but unless you're looking to dig into the guts of WSGI and Flask, you probably should leave this alone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was tempted to say the `request_finished` signal would work, but testing it out now, it does wait until the listener is finished before returning to the user.

So I think that leaves you with implementing a task queue- Flask has some documentation on [getting Celery based background tasks](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/patterns/celery/) working.  So when you reach your slow logging command, you'd instead just add the task to the Celery queue, finish your response to the user, then let a Celery worker take care of the task as it's able.