# Flask - Correct signal to subscribe to log after a request was finished?

Tags: python, flask

I want to log requests (ie. user page views) to a database, but I want only to log the request metadata to a DB after the request was finished and data was successfully sent to the client.

Does flask request_tearing_down is the correct signal to subscribe? How about request_finished?

Comment: I don't think this is really possible in a WSGI style application (which Flask is). The response is returned from the app and at that point leaves the domain of Flask to begin its journey back to the client. The `request_finished` signal is likely the best you can do without digging around inside the internals of whatever HTTP stack is hosting the WSGI Flask app.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like you don't want `request_finished`. From the docs:

> This signal is sent right before the response is sent to the client.

From what I gather, `request_tearing_down` is also triggered before a response is sent.

I don't think there is a specific signal that exists that you can subscribe to to do something after a response has been sent. You might be able to modify Flask's code to add one yourself.

You best option might be to make the logging happen asynchronously so that it doesn't delay the response. You could do this yourself with threads or subprocesses, or you could use a library like [Celery](http://www.celeryproject.org/) to do some of the work for you.

Also see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19731125/1263415)